# Using negative margin inside a DIV with overflow property

Tags: html, css, overflow

I have a container, and inside that I have an image. Jscrollpane applied on the container, so its overflow hidden. I would like to change the position of the image with negative margin to be outside the container. But I can't because overflow:hidden is active. I changed it to overflow-x, but it's not working.

View online: http://jsfiddle.net/e6444/1/

```
 #container {
    width:500px;
    height:300px;
    background:grey;
    overflow-y:hidden;
    margin:0 auto;
}

#image {
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
    background:url("http://www.audiapproved.com/ImgThumb?id=16033-500-335");
    margin:0 0 0 -30px;
}

<div id="container">
    <div id="image">
        Text, text, text Text, text, text Text, text, text Text, text, text
    </div>
</div>
```

I would like the following: http://jsfiddle.net/e6444/2/ but with overflow property. (i need it for jscrollpane plugin)

Comment: So what is the result you want to achieve?

Comment: You don't seem to have many options here.  Either remove the overflow or move the image to be outside of the container.

Comment: Mabye its just me but i dont get it, what you would like to achive?

Comment: What do you want to do?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/e6444/2/ I would like to see this, but with overflow property. I can't remove this property because I need it for jscrollpane.. and I can't move the image outside. I can trick only with css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add another container for your overflow:hidden content.

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="content">
        This is my content that can be overflow:hidden
    </div>
    <div id="image">
        Text, text, text Text, text, text Text, text, text Text, text, text
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wLrCU/1/